# Converting a Julian Date to datetime in Visual Studio (SSIS Package)

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, data-warehouse, jdedwards

I am trying to build an SSIS package to allow conversion of a Oracle Julian Date to a datetime field for a SQL server DB in MS Visual Studio 2013. What tool would I use to convert my current Julian field into a datetime?

Specifically, I need to convert a date such as: 115365 to 12/31/2015,in my DB. I cant seem to figure out how to use a Derived Column to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I used to convert to a DB DATE. This is done in a Derived Column:

```
DATEADD("day",(DT_I4)[COLUMN] % 1000,DATEADD("yyyy",(DT_I4)[COLUMN] / 1000,(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"12/31/1899"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, @JulianDate / 1000 - 1900, @JulianDate % 1000 - 1)
```

And the other way is

```
SELECT  DATENAME(YEAR, GETDATE()) + RIGHT('00' + DATENAME(DAYOFYEAR, GETDATE()), 3)
```

Comment: Are you plugging this into a Derived Column expression editor? I cant seem to pass this when I try to do so.